# Trouble setting up PWM using bitwise operations PIC12F615 MPLAB X

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, microchip, mplab

For whatever reason, I have never been able to use bitshifts in MPLAB. Here is some code I'm working on to setup PWM on the [PIC12F615](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC12F615):

```
// configuration of PWM
void configPWM(void) {
    // Disable the PWM pin (CCP1) output drivers by setting the associated TRIS bit.
    TRISIO |= 1 << 2;       // 
    // Set the PWM period by loading the PR2 register. 
    PR2 = 0x65;             // from datasheet???
    // Configure the CCP module for the PWM mode by loading the CCP1CON register with the appropriate values. 0b00001100
    CCP1CON = 0x0C;         // 
    // Set the PWM duty cycle by loading the CCPR1L register and DC1B bits of the CCP1CON register.
    CCPR1L = 0x88;          // about half duty cycle
    // Configure and start Timer2:
        // Clear the TMR2IF interrupt flag bit of the PIR1 register.
    PIR1 &= ~(1 << 1);      // clearing bit 1
        // Set the Timer2 prescale value by loading the T2CKPS bits of the T2CON register.
    T2CON |= 1 << 1;        // setting "1x"
        // Enable Timer2 by setting the TMR2ON bit of the T2CON register.
    T2CON |= 1 << 2;        // setting bit 1
    // Enable PWM output after a new PWM cycle has started:
        // Wait until Timer2 overflows (TMR2IF bit of the PIR1 register is set).
    while(!(PIR1 & (1 << 1))) {
        __delay_ms(1);
    }
        // Enable the CCP1 pin output driver by clearing the associated TRIS bit.
    TRISIO &= ~(1 << 2);    // clearing GP2, CCP1 pin
}
```

As you can see I'm using bitshifts heavily to set and clear bits. However, I get this error 9 times on the block of code above when I do an MISRA check:

> main.c:72:17: [misra-c2012-10.1] Operands shall not be of an
> inappropriate essential type

Is there a better way to do this? On TM4C123G I did not have this issue using Keil uVision4 IDE. I'm currently using MPLAB X IDE v5.45.

Comment: You are only allowed to do a shift on an unsigned value. Wkat happes if you switch to `1U <<1`for your shift?

Comment: Holy crap that worked. So weird. I never would have thought of that!!

Answer (score 0):

So i make an answer :
MISRA don't allow shift operations on signed types, because the result depends on how your compiler chooses to represent types and how it performs shifts.
So for e.g. you had to switch to:

```
   TRISIO |= 1u << 2;
```